# Execute require contents more then once

Tags: node.js, require

Let's say I have an `log.js` with `console.log('hi')`, and in another file I have this:

```
require('./example.js')
require('./example.js')
require('./example.js')
```

I only get one `console.log` of `hi`.

What do I have to do so that `hi` is logged 3 times?

Comment: Redesign your code to work differently.  Modules are cached.  If you want to run code multiple times, then you should export a function that you can then call multiple times.  There's no need to reload and reparse code just to execute it more than one time.

Comment: I have my reasons... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377091/testing-stdin-stdout-with-mock-cli-unable-to-make-second-call-to-file

Answer (score 1):

```
require('./example.js')
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./example.js')]
require('./example.js')
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./example.js')]
require('./example.js')
```